# scope value change doesn't get caught by $watch in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am following the documentation from [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog). Here's the directive I created as suggested.

```
.directive('setFocusIf', function() {
  return {
    link: function($scope, $element, $attr) {
      $scope.$watch($attr.setFocusIf, function(value) {
        if (value) { $element[0].focus(); }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

And my markup:

```
<input set-focus-if="hasFocus" ng-focus="hasFocus = false">

<button type="button" ng-click="addItem()">Add</button>
```

`addItem()` function does something and sets the value of `hasFocus` to `true`. But, this doesn't work and the element doesn't get focus. While debugging I found out that the `$watch` itself isn't getting called.

**However**, when I set the value like `ng-click="hasFocus = true"` in the button instead of setting `hasFocus` to `true` in the `addItem()` function, it works perfectly fine.

I tried enclosing it in `$apply` but doesn't seem to work, and I am not very clear on its internals. I think I am missing some fundamentals here, can someone please point out what's the difference between these two approaches.

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7Q0hBmvzReiX4OOidkYg?p=preview) showing the problem

Comment: try $element and remove $element[0]

Comment: The problem here is that `$watch` doesn't get triggered. So your suggestion won't apply there.

Comment: Can you create a plunker?

Comment: can you provide html code where you added controller. or just create fiddle

Comment: you can apply $scope.$watch on hasFocus rather than attribute

Comment: @chiragchavda.ks [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7Q0hBmvzReiX4OOidkYg?p=preview)

Comment: in your plunker your controller scope start and end. you have to put directive in controller.

Comment: @Салман your plunker the the button and input box are outside the controller. `<div ng-controller="FirstCtrl"></div>` . You should put your input box and button inside this div.

Comment: So you figured it out? the plunker works fine for me..

Comment: @SyedSuhailAhmed OK, that was a mistake in plunker though, but it still doesn't work in my code. :P Any idea?

Comment: It means its working on your plucker but not in code.. how is that possible if you have written same code both ends

Comment: Not sure, I'm using ui-router so no chance of controller scope problem like this one. besides, everything is same.

Comment: Actually I just noticed, it works for the first time only, and not on subsequent clicks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after trying out different stuff, I figured out that it has something to do with the dot in scope.

I changed this

```
<input set-focus-if="hasFocus" ng-focus="hasFocus = false">
```

to this

```
<input set-focus-if="focus.hasFocus" ng-focus="focus.hasFocus = false">
```

And ofcourse, `addItem` now sets `$scope.focus.hasFocus = true;`

It works perfectly now...

On a side note, I need to understand if setting the focus this way is right or not. Because this won't work for multiple element requiring focus on different occasions/events unless the directive is modified to work accordingly. But still it wouldn't be efficient since `$watch` would be called for every element that has `set-focus-if` directive.